# How to execute node js functions one after another which dynamically listed using their names in a string array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to achieve following in my Node.js program.

1. How create a function array from their names provided in strings?
2. How to execute those functions one after another. Not asynchronously.
3. How to pass parameters for those functions.

Suggest me a better approach to achieve this or code snippet somewhere already implemented this.

Comment: Can you add some sample code?

Comment: Need to clarify more?

Comment: Yes. Need more clarification. Does this functions belong to a file or object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this;

```js
function foo(v){console.log("foo: ",v)};
function bar(v){console.log("bar: ",v)};

var funs = ["foo", "bar"],
       i = 0;
while (i < funs.length) this[funs[i]](i++);
```

Well of course your functions definitions might reside in a particular scope and you may need to invoke them from within whatnot..! In that case you can of course wrap the above code in a function and bind it to whatever scope your function definitions are made in. Such as

```js
var obj = {
           foo: function(v){console.log("foo: ",v)},
           bar: function(v){console.log("bar: ",v)}
          },
   funs = ["foo", "bar"],
 runner = function(a){
            var i = 0;
            while (i < a.length) this[a[i]](i++);
          }.bind(obj);
     
runner(funs);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1. Define the list

```
var functions = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
```

### Step 2. Iterate the list

We iterate over the function list and call the `__call` function.

```
functions.forEach(function(f){
   __call(f);
});
```

### Step 3. Call the function

This step is dependent on framework. If you're using node, you have to use the `global` object. If you're using a browser (HTML) you have to use the `window` object.

For the former, use:

```
__call = function(f) { 
    var args = []; 
    for(var i = 1; i<arguments.length; i++){
        args.push(arguments[i])
    }; 
    console.log(args);
    global[f].apply(null, args); 
};
```

For the latter, use:

```
 __call = function(f) { 
    var args = []; 
    for(var i = 1; i<arguments.length; i++){
        args.push(arguments[i])
    }; 
    console.log(args);
    window[f].apply(null, args); 
};
```

The only difference is we're using the `window` or `global` dictionary to access the function.

**EDIT: Added passing parameters.**

Answer (score 0):

1. You can call a function by its name like this:

   const functions = ['index', 'push'...];

   ```
   functions[0]() // write your parameters inside. this will call 'index'
   ```
2. If those function are not async, just write the callings one after another. If they are async, use a helper like async.waterfall or async.series.
3. see 1.